# couchbase on docker where to replace ip?

Tags: docker, couchbase

[couchbase docker guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/couchbase/) says at the bottom:

> "Make sure to replace the IP address with the IP address of your
>   Docker Machine or localhost if Docker is running locally."

I have access to the admin ui via `http://192.168.99.100:8091/` where do I replace now the IP in the settings there? I cant find it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mis-interpreting the documentation. It says

> Couchbase Web Console is a console that allows to manage a Couchbase
>   instance. It can be seen at:
>
> http://192.168.99.100:8091/
>
> Make sure to replace the IP address with the IP address of your Docker Machine or localhost if Docker is running locally.

Since you have said that you can access that IP address, then you don't need to do anything. In other words, Docker is **not** "running locally".